# ¿Es posible y como trasponer resultados de una columna a filas dinamicamente? SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi consulta la indico inmediatamente:

Ejemplo, poseo la tabla 'calendario':

```
Código | Tramo  | días
Semana1|08001800| 5
Semana1|DESCANSO| 2
Semana2|15302100| 4
Semana2|21000800| 1
Semana2|DESCANSO| 2
Semana3|09001900| 5
Semana3|DESCANSO| 2
Semana3|08001800| 2
```

La tabla indicada arriba es una calendarización y mi duda es si la query de resultado se pude obtener de la siguiente forma:

```
Código | Tramo  | Tramo  | Tramo  | Tramo  | Tramo  | Tramo  | Tramo  | Tramo  | Tramo  |
Semana1|08001800|08001800|08001800|08001800|08001800|DESCANSO|DESCANSO|
Semana2|15302100|15302100|15302100|15302100|21000800|DESCANSO|DESCANSO|
Semana3|09001900|09001900|09001900|09001900|09001900|DESCANSO|DESCANSO|08001800|08001800|
```

En teoría debe leer el 'TRAMO' y repetirlo la cantidad de veces que indica en 'días' y debe repetirlo hacia la derecha en columnas y sin repetir el 'codigo'.

De momento no he avanzado en el código ya que no se me ocurre como realizarlo, estuve pensando en utilizar CASE pero no me resulta.

¿alguna idea? ¿se entiende?, es dínamico ya que la consulta se extendera hacia el lado de acuerdo a la cantidad de días que posea el tramo.

Favor su orientación.

Comment: Apoyo lo que dice @gbianchi me da la sensación que la solución debes implementarla desde otro punto de vista, ¿la consulta SQL en que la estás mostrando?

Comment: Mediante queries no lograrías llegar a ese formato que deseas, lo que podrías es usar tablas dinámicas en otros programas con los datos obtenidos como Excel, a menos que tengas conocimientos de B.I. y te des el tiempo de armar el cubo y luego darle ese formato. Saludos.

Comment: Se me ocurren algunas posibilidades, desde un CASE complejo, un cursor o trabajar con `PIVOT`, pero la principal dificultad es la cantidad de columnas, es decir la cantidad máxima de `Tramos`,  ¿es un dato conocido y fijo?

Comment: La cantidad maxima es X, sin embargo, como mucho debería ser hasta 14 columnas de 'tramo' (2 semanas).

Respecto a los demás comentarios, más allá de si es buena o no, o si el planteamiento debe realizarse por otro programa o incluso innecesaria, la consulta es simple. ¿es posible?, si no lo es, no lo es, si es compleja, lo será o simplemente no responder.

Comment: @leonbloy, estoy de acuerdo en gran parte, pero no pasa por ser masoquista, a veces se imponen restricciones, como por ejemplo que el único lenguaje de desarrollo sea `SQL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta no es la solución más óptima, creo que hay posibilidad de plantearlo de una forma más sencilla, pero al menos este método resolvería tu pregunta.

En primer lugar, me baso en tu límite máximo de tramos, esto es importante, por que si este número es indeterminado, hay que pasar si o sí por una consulta dinámica que es una capa más de complejidad: averiguar el máximo y escribir una sentencia dinámica sobre la base de lo que te estoy respondiendo.

El otro tema importante es que en principio, en tu ejemplo, no indicas un campo para manejar un orden cronológico, lo voy a agregar a lógica con el orden con el que armaste el ejemplo.

Lo primero es definir la tabla con los casos del ejemplo, más el orden que hablábamos:

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo TABLE (
    NroTramo    INT,
    Codigo      VARCHAR(255),
    Tramo       VARCHAR(255),
    CantTramos  INT
)

INSERT INTO @Ejemplo (Codigo, Tramo, CantTramos, NroTramo)
SELECT  'Semana1','08001800',5, 1   UNION
SELECT  'Semana1','DESCANSO',2, 2   UNION
SELECT  'Semana2','15302100',4, 1   UNION
SELECT  'Semana2','21000800',1, 2   UNION
SELECT  'Semana2','DESCANSO',2, 3   UNION
SELECT  'Semana3','09001900',5, 1   UNION
SELECT  'Semana3','DESCANSO',2, 2   UNION
SELECT  'Semana3','08001800',2, 3
```

Lo siguiente, es armar una tabla de Días por tramo, como mencionaste 2 semanas como máximo, en el peor de los casos tendríamos 1 tramo de 14 días, por lo que generaremos 14 registros, de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @DiasPorTramo TABLE (
    Dias    INT
)

INSERT INTO @DiasPorTramo (Dias)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14)
```

Esta tabla la usaremos para generar otra Intermedia, dónde básicamente vamos a generar un registro por cada día de cada tramo, de aquí es que te comento que es una solución no del todo óptima y será práctica en función del volumen de datos que manejes. Para armar nuestra tabla intermedia:

```
DECLARE @TablaIntermedia TABLE (
    NroTramo        INT,
    Codigo          VARCHAR(255),
    Tramo           VARCHAR(255),
    NroDia          INT,
    TramoColumna    VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @TablaIntermedia  (NroTramo, Codigo, Tramo, NroDia)
SELECT  E.NroTramo,
    E.Codigo,
    E.Tramo,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY E.Codigo ORDER BY E.Codigo,E.NroTramo)
    FROM @Ejemplo E
    LEFT JOIN @DiasPorTramo D
        ON 1 = 1
        AND E.CantTramos >= D.Dias
    ORDER BY E.Codigo, E.NroTramo

UPDATE  @TablaIntermedia
    SET TramoColumna = 'Tramo' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, NroDia)
```

Viendo un solo caso, por ejemplo `Semana1`, así quedarían los datos:

```
NroTramo Codigo     Tramo       NroDia  TramoColumna
======== ========== =========== ======= ============
1,00     Semana1    08001800    1,00    Tramo1
1,00     Semana1    08001800    2,00    Tramo2
1,00     Semana1    08001800    3,00    Tramo3
1,00     Semana1    08001800    4,00    Tramo4
1,00     Semana1    08001800    5,00    Tramo5
2,00     Semana1    DESCANSO    6,00    Tramo6
2,00     Semana1    DESCANSO    7,00    Tramo7
```

Con estos datos ya queda mucho más claro como podemos hacer unas consultas para llegar al resultado deseado:

Usando un `GROUP BY`, `MAX` y un `CASE` podemos hacer esto (en la práctica habría que agregar el resto de los tramos hasta el 14):

```
SELECT  Codigo,
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo1' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo2' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo3' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo3',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo4' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo4',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo5' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo5',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo6' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo6',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo7' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo7',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo8' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo8',
        MAX(CASE WHEN TramoColumna = 'Tramo9' THEN Tramo END) 'Tramo9'
    FROM @TablaIntermedia
    GROUP BY Codigo
```

Usando `PIVOT` también es posible (no recuerdo si lo tienes disponible en 2008):

```
SELECT  Codigo, Tramo1, Tramo2, Tramo3, Tramo4, Tramo5, Tramo6, Tramo7, Tramo8, Tramo9 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Codigo, Tramo, TramoColumna
        FROM @TablaIntermedia
    ) s
    PIVOT
    (
      MAX(Tramo) FOR TramoColumna IN (Tramo1, Tramo2, Tramo3, Tramo4, Tramo5, Tramo6, Tramo7, Tramo8, Tramo9 )
    ) p
```

En ambos casos la salida es la misma:

```
Codigo  Tramo1      Tramo2      Tramo3      Tramo4      Tramo5      Tramo6      Tramo7      Tramo8      Tramo9
======= =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== ===========
Semana1 08001800    08001800    08001800    08001800    08001800    DESCANSO    DESCANSO    NULL        NULL
Semana2 15302100    15302100    15302100    15302100    21000800    DESCANSO    DESCANSO    NULL        NULL
Semana3 09001900    09001900    09001900    09001900    09001900    DESCANSO    DESCANSO    08001800    08001800
```

Como te decía, no es la solución más óptima, te sugiero que esperes alguna otra respuesta antes de darla por buena (obviamente si te resulta útil).

### Actualización

Una solución muchísimo mejor es la siguiente:

```
SELECT  Codigo,
    MAX(CASE WHEN 1 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 2 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 3 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 4 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 5 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 6 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 7 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 8 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END),
    MAX(CASE WHEN 9 BETWEEN (Acumulado - CantTramos) + 1 AND Acumulado THEN Tramo END)
    FROM (SELECT    T.*,
            SUM(CantTramos) OVER (partition by Codigo order by Codigo, NroTramo) as 'Acumulado'
        from (SELECT 
            Codigo, 
            Tramo,
            NroTramo, 
            CantTramos 
            FROM @Ejemplo) t
    ) TT
    GROUP BY Codigo
```

Esta solución no requiere generar una tabla intermedia, perdón por arrancar por la solución más difícil, pero no estaba seguro de poder resolverlo de otra forma

Comment: Patricio, que puedo decirte ... es decir ... La primera respuesta que me diste funcionó a la perfección!! y ahora probare con la actualización sin embargo, la primera funciono de inmediato y se adapta a mi tabla y consulta!! muchas gracias!!!!